# str_extract: Extracting exactly nth word from a string

Tags: r, regex, string, stringr

I know this question has been asked at several places, but I didnt see a precise answer to this.

So I am trying to extract exactly the 2nd word from a string("trying to") in R with the help of regex. I do not want to use unlist(strsplit)

```
sen= "I am trying to substring here something, but I am not able to"

str_extract(sen, "trying to\\W*\\s+((?:\\S+\\s*){2})")
```

Ideally I want to get "here" as an output, but I am getting "trying to substring here"

Comment: Why `here` is what you need to extract? It is not the 3rd word in a sentence. Do you want to extract a streak of non-whitespace chars after `trying to` + 1 or more whitespaces?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew.. sorry for the confusion, I have edited my que

Comment: Try  `str_match(sen, "trying to\\W+\\S+\\W+(\\S+)")[,2]` or `str_match(sen, "trying to\\s+\\S+\\s+(\\S+)")[,2]`

Comment: @d.b, thanks for your response, but first I want to locate a specifc string in my sentence and from there i want to extract the exact second word. your solution seems not for that

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew.. thanks it worked like a charm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may actually *capture* the word you need with `str_match`:

```
str_match(sen, "trying to\\W+\\S+\\W+(\\S+)")[,2]
```

Or

```
str_match(sen, "trying to\\s+\\S+\\s+(\\S+)")[,2]
```

Here, `\S+` matches 1 or more chars other than whitespace, and `\W+` matches one or more chars other than word chars, and `\s+` matches 1+ whitespaces.

Note that in case your "words" are separated with more than whitespace (punctuation, for example) use `\W+`. Else, if there is just whitespace, use `\s+`.

The `[,2]` will access the first captured value (the part of text matched with the part of the pattern inside the first unescaped pair of parentheses).

Answer (score 5):

Since you also tagged `stringr`, I will post the `word` solution,

```
library(stringr)

word(sub('.*trying to ', '', sen), 2)
#[1] "here"
```

Comment: This is a great solution. But when I have multiple spaces between words, this doesn't work. Because it returns whitespace as a word.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `sub`

```
sub("^.*\\btrying to\\s+\\w+\\s+(\\w+).*", "\\1", sen)
#[1] "here"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `strsplit`. First separate `sen` into two parts at `"trying to "` and then extract second word of the second part.

```
sapply(strsplit(sen, "trying to "), function(x) unlist(strsplit(x[2], " "))[2])
#[1] "here"
```

Answer (score 1):

`str_split` is sometimes a popular choice. Call the nth word using [1,2], which returns the second word, [1,3] for the third, and so forth.

```
library(stringr)

#Data
sen= "I am trying to substring here something, but I am not able to"

#Code
str_split(sen, boundary("word"), simplify = T)[1,2]
#> [1] "am"
```

Created on 2018-08-16 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: This is a good solution. But in the string "23. Qxe4+ Bf5 ({+2.57} 23" delete the "+" in the second word.